# how to handle null values in donut chart to avoid console errors

Tags: d3.js

If all the values in my chart are 0. my console throws errors like

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M4.133182947122317e-15,-67.5A67.5,67.5 0 1,1 NaN,NaNL0,0Z"
>
> Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"

It happens only when all values are zero. How can i handle this?
i tried this; but no luck

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d){ return d.value; });
```

[Here's my pen](http://codepen.io/separ1/pen/aBMPGm?editors=1010)

Comment: If all values are zero, how should the chart look like? It doesn't make much sense to display a chart for such data. Also, I see no errors in the console on codepen.

Comment: chart will not be displayed since values are zero. in codepen console even i am not getting errors but in my local i am getting. If there's any insight you could give seeing the errors and functions corresponding to those